# What do people mean when they say "Craftable Hat"

Tags: team-fortress-2

When someone says "Trading x for a craftable hat" (generally comes in the form of "Trading one refined per craftable hat), what exactly is it that they mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term refers to any hat that can and will be used in the [Rebuild Headgear crafting recipe](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Random_crafting_recipes#Random_Headgear) (combine any 2 hats for a random hat).

If the description of a hat says **(Not Usable in Crafting)**, then that hat is uncraftable, and generally sells for less as it can't be used in creating another hat.

Comment: So why would anyone trade a hat (3 refined min.) for 1 refined?

Comment: @Mr Smooth: The market price of most normal hats is lower than crafting value, and that's precisely why people would rather trade than craft.